# Option whose purpose is unknown even for the man page writer

Tags: linux, fdisk

Every now and then I end up messing with my disks and I have to use `fdisk`. I have noticed however, that the option `-C` or `--cylinders` has a particular description:

```
"Specify the number of cylinders of the disk. I have no idea why anybody would want to do so"
```

So this raises a question: Is there a reason (legacy, completeness, etc) that leads to the existence of this option? Will an incorrect use (misspelling `-c` with `-C` for example) would lead to a major problem, like data destruction?

Comment: Please show what research you've done in finding out the answer. I took a few seconds to find this link, which gives examples of the option you are asking about. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, I couldn't find anything that exactly address the question I posted. Would you please be so kind to elaborate an answer that summarizes the facts present in the link you provided that address my very question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completeness, I suppose. The harddisk geometry is described by the number of sectors, heads, and cylinders (`-S`, `-H`, and `-C`), and this information is set from the BIOS or the harddisk itself. So in case it is wrong, you need some way to override it. However, only the first two influence calculations, so using `-C` hasn't really applications.

Comment: So, if I understood you, `-C` has _never_ had any applications since as far as I'm concerned, `-S` and `-H` have always existed along `-C`, so it was pointless from the beginning. Isn't it right?

Comment: Unless some new calculations that are based on number of cyclinders were introduced somewhere later on, no, it doesn't have applications. But the code is similar to `-S` and `-H`, so I can understand the reflex to add it "just in case" while writing this code. (All of this would only have been useful for early harddrives, anyway).

Comment: You can use Cylinders to describe limits for Partitions... as an alternative to Sectors/Heads. This is also useful reading :- http://www.linfo.org/cylinder.html